# How to modprobe radeon and turn off card at start with systemd?

Tags: arch-linux, startup, systemd

ArchLinux has completly replaced `rc.conf` with `systemd`. I used `/etc/rc.local` to modprobe `radeon` module and turn it off using vgaswitcheroo.

```
modprobe radeon && echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

But, there is no `rc.conf` in ArchLinux anymore. How can I do it with `systemd` ?

Comment: You should be using `/etc/modules`, not your init system for this.

Answer (score 1):

So the first thing you will do is [have Arch automatically load the `radeon` module at boot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_modules#Loading).

To do this, add a file to the `/etc/modules-load.d` directory, for example:

```
# echo radeon > /etc/modules-load.d/radeon.conf
```

The second thing is to have vgaswitcheroo do its magic to switch off the disconnected graphics adapter. [Arch has a `systemd-vgaswitcheroo-units` package](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=60939) which may help you accomplish this. It echoes OFF at startup, and ON at shutdown. To enable it, use:

```
# systemctl enable vgaswitcheroo.service
```